# ROC Curves Turorial

Tags: machine-learning, svm, classification, roc

Guys I am looking for a third party software that applies classifiers (like SVM, multilayer perceptrons, I head libsvm is quite good) and also more important any tutorial about ROC Curves as I want to learn how to do them. The ones I found In google are not really helpful so if you know anything else that would be nice. Could somebody provide me something similar?

Comment: I have already tried Matlab btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end up using **R** you should take a look at the [ROCR package](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/).